# Allow unknown keys but validated values in schema

Tags: validation, cerberus

What is the best way to validate a dict where the keys are unknown but the values have a definite schema.
For example:

```
data = {
'name': 'test',
'department': {
    'unknown_key': {
        'known_key': 'good',
        'unknown_key': 'bad'
    }
}}
```

I've tried

```
schema = {
'name': {
    'type': 'string'
},
'department': {
    'type': 'dict',
    'allow_unknown': {
        'schema': {
            'type': 'dict',
            'schema': {'known_key': {'type': 'string'},
                       'must_have_key': {'type': 'string'}}}
    },
}}
```

But this has failed as the validation passes. It should have failed on both the missing `must_have_key` and the `unknown_key`. Have I defined something wrong?

Comment: Maybe there should be a way to prevent `allow_unknown` from propagating through all the nested subschemas?

Comment: you can override `allow_unknown` in subschemas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [valueschema](http://docs.python-cerberus.org/en/stable/validation-rules.html#valueschema) rule to define rules for abritrary values data in a mapping:

```
schema = {
    'name': {'type': 'string'},
    'department': {
        'type': 'dict',
        'valueschema': {
            'type': 'dict',
            'schema':  {
                'known_key': {'type': 'string'},
                'must_have_key': {'type': 'string', 'required': True}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How to define `valuerules` (a new name for `valueschema`) for a dict type, where are the top-level key names are unknown?